# Retain Cycle in closure

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, reference, retain

I try to implement some variant of Coordinator pattern, but I face problem with retain cycle in closure. It looks like that:

```
func goTo() {
    let coord = SecondViewCoordinator(nav: navigationController)
    add(coord)
    coord.start()
    coord.deinitIfNeeded = { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.free(coord)
    }
}
```

As you can see I set `deinitIfNeeded` and then, if in `SecondViewCoordinator` call `deinitIfNeeded?()` controller pops correctly, but reference to `SecondViewCoordinator` is still exist even though `childCoordinators` array is empty.

My Coordinator class looks like that:

```swift
class Coordinator {

    weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    var childCoordinators: [Coordinator] = []
    var deinitIfNeeded: (() -> ())?

    init(nav: UINavigationController?) {
        self.navigationController = nav
    }

    func add(_ coordinator: Coordinator) {
        childCoordinators.append(coordinator)
    }

    func free(_ coordinator: Coordinator) {
        childCoordinators = childCoordinators.filter({ $0 !== coordinator })
    } 
}
```

memory graph presents this:

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: A simple reproduction path would always be nice :)

Comment: In `func free(_ coordinator: Coordinator)`, you are not doing anything that nil the object that is not required anymore. You just filtered the array and release the object in unreachable corner.

Answer (score 6):

In

```
coord.deinitIfNeeded = { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.free(coord)
}
```

You are holding a strong reference to `coord` inside the closure. Try something like this;

```
coord.deinitIfNeeded = { [weak self, weak coord] in
    guard let self = self, let coord = coord else { return }
    self.free(coord)
}
```

The memory graph is giving a hint that this is the case (the right side says the strong reference is in a closure).

You could also set `coord.deinitIfNeeded` to `nil` inside the closure.

Comment: it's working. Thx. I was thinking to long about that and I haven't seen the obvious solution ;)